# Update record from binary file (part of project) (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, malloc, binaryfiles

I'm trying to change some information from binary file but I get segmentation fault. I have been trying to deal with it for hours.Suppose there are two teams which names are same. The names are wanted to change. But , I get segmentation fault.
**(Problem)Suppose there are two teams which names are same. The names are wanted to change. But , I get segmentation fault.** Thanks for all appreciated answers.

```
team_name,   city   ,   stadium  ,fdate, colors
the team is in binary file
manunited,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd
chelsea,london,stamford_bridge,1905,blue-whte
manunited,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd

----------------------------------------
example input

update
update team_name=newcastle,founding_date=2014 in teams where team_name=manunited
----------------------------------------
output
**segmentation fault**
----------------------------------------
new output teams.bin should be
newcastle,manchester,old_trafford,2014,black-rd
chelsea,london,stamford_bridge,1905,blue-whte
newcastle,manchester,old_trafford,2014,black-rd
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    char read_command[12];
    /*      checking insert     */
    char str1[100],str2[5],str3[18],space,str4[100];

    scanf("%s", read_command);

    if(strcmp(read_command,"update") == 0)
    {
        scanf("%s",str3);//read update from input code
        //printf("\nstr3=%s",str3);
        scanf("%s",str4);
        //printf("\nstr4=%s",str4);
        scanf("%c",&space);
            fgets(str1,100,stdin);
            //printf("\nstr1=%s",str1);
            updatefunc(str1,str4);
    }

    return 0;
}
void wherefunc(char *str,char *tag,char *id)
{
    char *token;
    int i=0;
    token = strtok(str,"=");
    strcpy(tag,token);
    token = strtok(NULL,"=");
    strcpy(id,token);
}
void updatefunc(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    FILE *fp;

    char tag[30];     // regard to the input it is team_name
    char id[30];     // regard to the input it is manunited

    /* regard to the input it will change first team_name then founding_date */
    char variablenew[30];
    /* regard to the input it will change first newcastle then 2014 */   
    char valuenew[30];


    char *tokenstr1;
    char *tokenstrnew;

    char *buff;
    buff =  (char*) malloc(strlen(str1) + 1);
    strcpy(buff,str1);
    char *token;

    const char space[2] = " ";
    const char comma[2] = ",";
    char tempstrs[10][100];
    char tempstrsnew[10][30];

    int i = 0, j = 0 ,c, ii;

    tokenstrnew = strtok(str2,comma);
    while (tokenstrnew != NULL)
    {
        //printf("  %s    %d \n",tokenstr1,i);
        strcpy(tempstrsnew[j],tokenstrnew);
        j++;
        tokenstrnew = strtok(NULL,comma);
    }
    //printf("%d      %s           %s",j,tempstrsnew[0],tempstrsnew[1]);


    tokenstr1 = strtok(buff,space);

    while (tokenstr1 != NULL)
    {
        /*      get rid of \n character  bcz of fgets()     */
        int len = strlen(tokenstr1);
        if (len > 0 && tokenstr1[len-1] == '\n') tokenstr1[len-1] = '\0';

        //printf("  %s    %d \n",tokenstr1,i);
        strcpy(tempstrs[i],tokenstr1);
        i++;
        tokenstr1 = strtok(NULL,space);
    }

        wherefunc(tempstrs[3],tag,id);  //every wherefunc to seperate "=" symbols
        //printf("\n\ntag = %s    id = %s",tag,id);
        //printf("\n\n%s",str2);
    if(strcmp(tempstrs[1],"teams") == 0)
    {

        fp=fopen("teams.bin", "rb+");
        if (!fp)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file %s", "teams.bin");
            exit(1);
        }

        teams *t;
        t=(teams*)malloc(sizeof(teams)*1000);
        int x = fread(t, sizeof(teams), 1000, fp);
        t = (teams*)realloc(t,x*sizeof(teams));

        for( ii = 0 ; ii < x ; ii++)
        {         
                if((strcmp(tag,"team_name") == 0) && (strcmp(id,t[ii].team_name) == 0))
                {

                    fread(&t[ii], sizeof(teams), 1, fp);

                    for(c = 0 ; c < j ; c++)
                    {
                        wherefunc(tempstrsnew[c],variablenew,valuenew);

                        if(strcmp(variablenew,"team_name") == 0)
                        {

                            strcpy(t[ii].team_name,valuenew);
                            fseek(fp, ii*sizeof(team), SEEK_SET);
                            fwrite(&t[ii], sizeof(teams), 1, fp);
                        }
                        else if(strcmp(variablenew,"founding_date") == 0)
                        {

                            t[ii].founding_date = atoi(valuenew) ;
                            fseek(fp, ii*sizeof(team), SEEK_SET);
                            fwrite(&t[ii], sizeof(teams), 1, fp);
                        }

                    }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

gdb result:

```
    (gdb) run
Starting program: /home/soner/Desktop/folder/a.out 
update
update team_name=newcastle,founding_date=2014 in teams where team_name=manunited

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
#1  0x000000000040fa91 in wherefunc (str=0x7fffffffd7a0 "team_name", 
    tag=0x7fffffffdbd0 "team_name", id=0x7fffffffdbf0 "2014") at seg.c:2321
#2  0x00000000004125b8 in updatefunc (
    str1=0x7fffffffdc90 "in teams where team_name=manunited\n", 
    str2=0x7fffffffdd00 "team_name=newcastle") at seg.c:3357
#3  0x000000000040109a in main () at seg.c:70
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x000000000040fa91 in wherefunc (str=0x7fffffffd7a0 "team_name", 
    tag=0x7fffffffdbd0 "team_name", id=0x7fffffffdbf0 "2014") at seg.c:2321
2321        strcpy(id,token);
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00000000004125b8 in updatefunc (
    str1=0x7fffffffdc90 "in teams where team_name=manunited\n", 
    str2=0x7fffffffdd00 "team_name=newcastle") at seg.c:3357
3357                            wherefunc(tempstrsnew[c],variablenew,valuenew);
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x000000000040109a in main () at seg.c:70
70              updatefunc(str1,str4);
(gdb)
```

Comment: don't cast `malloc` and check the returned pointer for `NULL`, and don't do `t = realloc(t, newsize)` because if it fails there will be no way to `free(t)`. Also, fix your code's indentation it's really hard to follow, maybe yu need some more functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Before `fread` it is also possible to save the file position by `ftell`(,etc).</del>
You need to `fseek` to position which had been stored prior to `fwrite`.

---

try this

```
fseek(fp, ii*sizeof(team), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&t[ii], sizeof(teams), 1, fp);
```

Comment: same output `manunited,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd
newcastle,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd
newcastle,manchester,old_trafford,2014,black-rd` @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner Since such should be written to the same file location and its output funny. Are you running the program from the correct state file? Do you used as it is already a file that has been updated by mistake?

Comment: @Soner `int x = fread(t, sizeof(teams), 1000, fp);` Since you have read all of the data You need to `rewind(fp);`.

Comment: firstly, thank you for your helps. However, I'm running correctly. After adding `rewind(fp);` , A problem occurs The `team_name` is changed successfully. But, `founding_date` is not changed. Also, next teams `founding_date` is changing. i.e. there is the information (2 teams) in binary file `manunited,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd chelsea,london,stamford_bridge,1905,blue-whte` ,                         Then runnig the code output is like this `newcastle,manchester,old_trafford,1878,black-rd chelsea,london,stamford_bridge,2014,blue-whte` Besides,I updated the code above as your saying

Comment: @Soner I think there is a need to update the respective field at the same time to process the same record.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove `for(c = 0 ; c < j ; c++)` the loop ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner for-loop is reversed(inside <-> outside). `for( ii = 0 ; ii < x ; ii++)` <--> `for(c = 0 ; c < j ; c++)` and `for(c = 0 ; c < j ; c++)` move to after `fread`.

Comment: There is wrong @BLUEPIXY , If I apply `rewind(fp);` or `fseek(fp, saveplace, SEEK_SET);` It changes just beginning of team ? Not searched one ?

Comment: @Soner no, i mean that `ii < x` record-loop { `c < j` update-loop }

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code in my question. Would you mind If checked by you ? @BLUEPIXY If I write updated my code manunited record still there. Changed record is added to file as new record(newcastle,2014). Changed record should be overwritten on manunited?

Comment: @Soner Hmm.. `{ }` correspondence is correct? Do you need `strcpy(id,valuenew);` ?

Comment: Ohh. No. But, problem is the changed information is added as new record. There should be overwritten on `manunited` record ? So, `manunited` record is still there. I explained in my updated question.

Comment: @Soner sorry. `fread` is  to to stop because there is no need to read the record,  Let's do direct `fseek`.

Comment: Waow. Now works. You are always a white knight. Know it. Thank you @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner Not at all. Was detour and I did not think too much in detail. Excuse me.

Comment: Thanks. By the way could you explain why `ii*sizeof(team)` in `fseek`? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner Size matches the case of the binary file(`b`).　It will move the record size(`sizeof(team)`) of the file position.

Comment: `rewind` also no longer required.

Comment: unfortunately, I got segmentation fault. I explain in edit question with gdb result. I need your advise @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner `tempstrsnew[c]` Since trying to split the what is already split at a repetition.

Comment: your code change to only once instead of performing the analysis of command for each record .

Comment: `wherefunc(tempstrsnew[c],variablenew,valuenew);` should be used number s of `j` . Because, in this example, `j` is two. In first time, it splits  `team_name=newcastle` then assign to `variablenew` and `valuenew` second time  `founding_date=2014 `  then again assign to `variablenew` and `valuenew` isn't it ? If it is not, what can I do ? Could you show me in your answer ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: should I take out `tempstrsnew[c]` from loop ? how ? `wherefunc(tempstrsnew[c],variablenew,valuenew);`  @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

Command analysis sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct field_U {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} Field_U;

typedef struct command_U {
    char *order;   //"update"
    char *rec_name;//record name. E.g "teams"
    int n;         //number of update field
    Field_U *field;//field and value pair of char *
    Field_U cond;  //condition a field pair.(one pair)
} Command_U;

void *allocate(size_t size){
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if(!p){
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc error!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return p;
}

char *str_dup(const char *str){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *p = allocate(len+1);
    memcpy(p, str, len+1);
    return p;
}

Command_U *analyze_U(const char *cmd){
    char temp1[128];//order field
    char temp2[32]; //record name
    char temp3[64]; //condition field
    if(3!=sscanf(cmd, "update %127s in %31s where %63s", temp1, temp2, temp3)){
        fprintf(stderr, "update syntax error!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    Command_U *cmdp = allocate(sizeof(*cmdp));
    int n = 0;
    char *p;
    for(p = temp1; p = strchr(p, '='); ++p){
        ++n;//count order field
    }
    cmdp->n = n;
    cmdp->field = allocate(n*sizeof(Field_U));
    int i;
    p = strtok(temp1, ",");
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        cmdp->field[i].name = str_dup(p);
        p = strchr(cmdp->field[i].name, '=');
        *p++ = '\0';
        cmdp->field[i].value = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    cmdp->rec_name  = str_dup(temp2);
    cmdp->cond.name = str_dup(temp3);
    p = strchr(cmdp->cond.name, '=');
    *p++ = '\0';
    cmdp->cond.value = p;
    cmdp->order = "update";
    return cmdp;
}

void drop_U(Command_U *cmd){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<cmd->n; ++i)
        free(cmd->field[i].name);
    free(cmd->field);
    free(cmd->rec_name);
    free(cmd->cond.name);
    free(cmd);
}

int main(){
    char command[] = "update team_name=newcastle,founding_date=2014 in teams where team_name=manunited\n";
    Command_U *cmd = analyze_U(command);
    if(!cmd) return -1;
    printf("order: %s\nrecord name: %s\n", cmd->order, cmd->rec_name);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < cmd->n; ++i){
        printf("update field%d: (%s, %s)\n", i+1, cmd->field[i].name, cmd->field[i].value);
    }
    printf("condition field : (%s, %s)\n", cmd->cond.name, cmd->cond.value);
    drop_U(cmd);
    return 0;
}
/* output
order: update
record name: teams
update field1: (team_name, newcastle)
update field2: (founding_date, 2014)
condition field : (team_name, manunited)
*/
```

---

a sample to use `Command_U`

```
int main(){
    char read_command[12];
    char command[256];
    Command_U *cmd;

    scanf("%s", read_command);

    if(strcmp(read_command,"update") == 0){
        fgets(command, sizeof(command),stdin);
        if(cmd = analyze_U(command)){
            updatefunc(cmd);
            drop_U(cmd);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
void updatefunc(Command_U *cmd){
    if(strcmp(cmd->rec_name, "teams") == 0){
        FILE *fp = fopen("teams.bin", "rb+");
        if (!fp){
            printf("Unable to open file %s", "teams.bin");
            exit(1);
        }

        teams t;
        long savepos;
        while(1){
            savepos = ftell(fp);
            if(0==fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp))//read one record
                break;
            if(strcmp(cmd->cond.name, "team_name")==0 && strcmp(cmd->cond.value, t.team_name) == 0){
                int i;
                for(i = 0 ; i < cmd->n ; i++){
                    if(strcmp(cmd->field[i].name, "team_name") == 0)
                        strcpy(t.team_name, cmd->field[i].value);
                    else if(strcmp(cmd->field[i].name, "founding_date") == 0)
                        t.founding_date = atoi(cmd->field[i].value);
                }
                fseek(fp, savepos, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
                fflush(fp);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard for me. I'm not experienced as much as you but thank you. I still have been trying to fix my problem(segmentatiton fault.)) @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Soner I have added the use sample. (I have not been tested.)